# Is there a way to create multiple notification channels in iOS like the system Calendar app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Android notification has 'channels' where you can enable/disable notifications based on channels. Like enable notification for "channel 1" but disable notification for "channel 2". Further more, to customise sound for different channels.
I wonder if there a similar implementation is iOS

I couldn't find any documentations. But I found the iOS Calendar App has similar settings.

[image: calendar Notification Center]

Comment: I think that the similar funcionality for iOs is Topics.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @ChanX